# How can I convert the captured pattern in a regex replace to uppercase?

Tags: regex, rust

I want to replace `/test/test1` with `TEST1:`. This is what I started with:

```
extern crate regex; // 1.0.1

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let regex_path_without_dot = Regex::new(r#"/test/(\w+)/"#).unwrap();

    let input = "/test/test1/test2/";

    // Results in "test1:test2/"
    let result = regex_path_without_dot.replace_all(input, "$1:");
}
```

I have tried using

```
let result = regex_path_without_dot.replace_all(&input, "$1:".to_uppercase());
```

but I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r, 's> std::string::String: std::ops::FnMut<(&'r regex::Captures<'s>,)>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:41
   |
10 |     let result = regex_path_without_dot.replace_all(&input, "$1:".to_uppercase());
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'r, 's> std::ops::FnMut<(&'r regex::Captures<'s>,)>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `regex::Replacer` for `std::string::String`
```

How do I implement this required trait? Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Regex::replace`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.0/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace) has the signature

```
pub fn replace<'t, R: Replacer>(&self, text: &'t str, rep: R) -> Cow<'t, str>
```

[`Replacer`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.1.0/regex/trait.Replacer.html) is implemented by:

- `&'a str`
- `ReplacerRef<'a, R> where R: Replacer`
- `F where F: FnMut(&Captures) -> T, T: AsRef<str>`
- `NoExpand<'t>`

There is no implementation for `String`, which is the direct cause of your error message. You could "fix" the error by converting your `String` into a string slice:

```
replace_all(&input, &*"$1:".to_uppercase()
```

Since the uppercase version is the same as the lowercase version, nothing will usefully change.

However, the implementation of `Replacer` by a closure *is* useful:

```
let result = regex_path_without_dot.replace_all(&input, |captures: &regex::Captures| {
    captures[1].to_uppercase() + ":"
});
```

---

> ```
> replace_all(&input, "$1:".to_uppercase())
> ```

This shows a fundamental error in understanding how this functionality works or in function precedence. This is the same as saying:

```
let x = "$1:".to_uppercase();
replace_all(&input, x)
```

Or, equivalently, since `1` is the uppercase `1` and `$` is the uppercase `$`:

```
let x = String::from("$1:");
replace_all(&input, x)
```

Calling a function like `to_uppercase` isn't magically deferred until "some later point".